# wingrotor rpm regulation; wind turbine regulation mechanism how it works?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, renewable-energy, wind-power, linkage

[image: Fig. 23. Regulating wingrotor, rotating in feeble wind, wingspan fully open.]

First figure-Fig.  23.    Regulating    wingrotor,   rotating in feeble wind, wingspan fully open.

[image: Fig. 24. Regulating wingrotor, rotating in strong wind, wingspan contracting.]

Second figure-Fig.  24.   Regulating   wingrotor, rotating in strong wind, wingspan contracting.

[image: Fig. 25. Regulating wingrotor at rest.Wings in neutral, facing each other.]

Third figure-Fig.  25.  Regulating  wingrotor   at  rest. Wings in neutral, facing each other.

Hello All,
Can somebody help me please with a proper description/explanation of the mechanism below? being not an EN native speaker, I am facing some difficulties with the wording.
Thank you.

*Fig. 23-25 show a regulating wingrotor.   The two endplates are   joined   together   by a steel   tube. This tube also forms the axis of the rotor and runs in two ball bearings in the support or engine house underneath the rotor. The wings are pivoted on tappets in the endplates.    The edges of the wings are connected by   the tension   rods     which are   pivoted at the edge of the wing. Two pairs of springs are fixed to the wings pulling them apart. Finally, a chain fixed to one wing   runs down   over pulleys through the hollow axis to a windlass.
Rotating at a normal speed the   wings keep the position shown   in   Fig.   23.    If    the   speed increases even slightly   above the normal, the centrifugal force acting on the wings begins to pull them round against the springload, so that less of the free wingsurface is exposed to the wind. It the speed again decreases the springs pull the wings back in their original position. The tension rods take   up and equalize the centrifugal forces relieving the wings of all strains and cause the wings to move together and to an equal degree.    The rotor is stopped by hauling the wings in neutral position with the aid of the chain and windlass.

The speed regulation is, according to tests with models, excellent. From a wind of 3 meters per sec. to a wind of 10 v. m. per sec. (6-20 miles per hour) the speed of the regulating wingrotor increases only l0-15 %.    No   matter how gusty the wind is, the rotor works like a clock, the regulation answering instantly to an increase in the windspeed. The regulating arrangement hardly   adds any complication s or wearing parts as tappets and rods have only a very slight movement and are stationary   most   of   the   time.   For    this    reason    no oiling of these parts is required.    Standing idle    with the opening facing the wind, the rotor swings   gently   to alterations in the direction of   the wind   as   if it   should have   an invisible   vane.   Resistance in this position is also quite small, so that the rotor standing idle is not stressed even in a storm.   If   the regulating   wings rotor is built tall it is equipped with a stayed mast inside the tube joining the endplates and the bearings are fixed round this central mast.   The   regulating   wingrotor   is   from   every point of   view   an   ideal   air   motor   combining   simplicity   of design, with strength and excellent speed regulation.*

Comment: Great, but what is your question?

Comment: I would like have/see how exactly this mechanisms works

Comment: There's "first figure, second figure, third figure" but no images. The missing images would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The operation is similar in a way with the [centrifugal governor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_governor).

[image]

**Figure: porter Governor source:[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_governor)**

E.g. in the image above you see the Porter governor. Those balls rotate about the axis (similar to the wingrotor), and the linkage moves depending on the spring/gravity to a new position. The movement pulls something that changes the operation of the machine.

in the case of the wingrotor, the wings acts as the fly balls.

You can watch a video of the governor in the following [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASIl3HWTT4U).